# Did the UK version of Terminator 2 censor out the lock picking scenes?

Tags: alternate-version, terminator-series, editing, censorship, terminator-2-judgment-day

In a [YouTube revue of *Terminator 2*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IVR9ebtcjQ), the narrator claims that the UK either tried to or actually did succeed in censoring out the scenes in which Sarah Connor picks several locks in the insane asylum because they apparently showed legitimate methods of lockpicking.

Did this actually happen? Is the UK version of *Terminator 2* lockpicking censored?

Comment: Not that I recall - but I only saw UK TV and subsequent DVD and Blu-Ray releases, not the original cinema release.

Comment: Learning the "secret" method of picking locks is as useful as learning that the "secret" to playing piano is to press the black and white keys that match the marks on the sheet music, or that the "secret" to juggling 7 balls is to continually throw them into the air and catch them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes they did, from [whatculture](https://whatculture.com/film/6-bizarrely-specific-movie-moments-uk-censors-banned?page=3)

> Remember that scene in Terminator 2 where Sarah Connor picks the lock
>   in the mental asylum with paper clips? It was actually for real. Turns
>   out Linda Hamilton was actually a skilled lock picker. Who knew?
>
> **The scene made it into the UK cinematic cut of T2, but the BBFC was having none of it when it came to the movie's home video release.**
>
> Why? Over concerns that criminals might replay the sequence in the
>   comfort of their own home and use it as an instructional video about
>   the art of breaking and entering.

[Movie-censorship.com](https://www.movie-censorship.com/report.php?ID=864124) elaborates on all this cuts.

Comment: In all the versions I have seen on TV and I did at one point have a DVD of it (but that was a Region 1 disc not a UK one) the scene is shown, at least to some degree. Having said that it has been a while and the scene was only a couple of seconds iirc, so it may of been "trimmed" . To be frank anyone wanting to learn such things can find far more detailed videos via a search engine or maybe even on YTube etc